# How to detect sem_open error in C

Tags: c, linux, posix, semaphore

when I initialize a new semaphore I would like to detect, if it was initialized properly, what´s the best way to do this?

According to [this link](http://www.vxdev.com/docs/vx55man/vxworks/ref/semPxLib.html#sem_open), which says that sem_open returns -1 if error occured, I made a decision:

```
if ((sem_t *semaphore = sem_open("/sem1", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0644, 1)) == -1) {handle error}
```

But this throws warning when I try to compile - comparison between pointer and integer. Is there any way to take care of that, please?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

On error, sem_open() returns SEM_FAILED, with errno set to indicate the error.

*Notice that the question code neglected to use SEM_FAILED; but rather specified '-1'; which resulted in the compiler warning "comparison between pointer and integer" indicated in the question.*

Check errno.  Something like this:

```
errno=0;  /* <---- This is an important thing I learned when using errno. */
if ((sem_t *semaphore = sem_open("/sem1", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0644, 0)) == SEM_FAILED) 
   {
   fprintf(stderr, "sem_open() failed.  errno:%d\n", errno);
   ...
```

Comment: also check that it returned SEM_FAILED

Comment: @MarshallTigerus, you are absolutely correct.  I have edited my answer to point this out clearly.  Thank you.

Comment: Hmm, this is weird, I did as you said, but it seems that if an error occures, it works just fine. But when that condition is false, then that semaphore is not created, I recognized it, because process stops on sem_wait(semaphore). (It is opened after initialization - set to 1).

Comment: @user1967718, that is weird.  Perhaps you should post your new code with the new question?